# Totaling sum of a class in a form

Tags: jquery, forms, html

I am trying to add a bunch of the same form up in another form. I think I am close, but I don't know where the disconnect is. I am trying to total up the form and then total up the totals in the forms to the end.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class "span12  exercise1 addWorkout">
            <img src="assets/img/plus01.jpg" class="addWorkout imgButton">Add A Workout</div>
        <!-- <img src="assets/img/minus01.png" class="delWorkout imgButton"> -->
        <div class="span12 workoutList" id="workoutList">
            <div class="cloneMe">
                <div class="row-fluid exercise1 one_rep_calc_container workoutOrgin span4">
                    <div class="oneWorkout">
                        <form>
                            <div class="span4">Weight
                                <input class="weight" type="number" name="weight" size="2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span4">Reps
                                <input class="reps" type="number" name="reps" size="2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span4">OneRepMax
                                <input class="one_rep_max" type="number" Name="oneRepMax" size="2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span4">TotalWeight
                                <input class="totalWeight" type="number" Name="totalWeight" size="2">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <!-- <img src="assets/img/plus01.jpg" class="addWorkout exercise1 imgButton">
 -->
                        <img src="assets/img/minus01.png" class="delWorkout imgButton">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span12 workoutResults">
            <form>
                <div class="span4">Total
                    <input class="totalAll" id="subtotal" type="number" name="total" size="2">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('.totalWeight').change(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parents('.workoutResults .one_rep_calc_container');
    var totalWeight = parseInt(parent.find('.totalWeight').val(), 10);
    var totalAll = parseInt(parent.find('.totalAll').val(), 10);

    if (weight > 0) {
        var totalWeightval = 0;
        $('.totalWeight').each(function () {
            totalWeightval += parseFloat(this.value);
        });
        parent.find('.totalAll').val(totalWeightval);
    } else {
        parent.find('.totalAll');
    }
});
```

any suggestions on how i could better organize my code that would be great as well.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? are the inputs updating or not? My advice, double check your parent selector because it is not consistent with your markup and try to refine the logic for your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = $(this).parents('.workoutResults .one_rep_calc_container');
```

`parents` looks for **all** possible parent elements that match the selector. You should be using `closest` instead.

---

```
var totalWeight = parseInt(parent.find('.totalWeight').val(), 10);
```

How many inputs with the class `totalWeight` are there? One or multiple? Later you use `$('.totalWeight').each(...)`, which indicates there will be multiple, however `parent.find('.totalWeight').val()` only makes sense if there is a single one.

---

```
if (weight > 0) {
```

You haven't defined a variable `weight` yet (unless it's a global variable you didn't show), so this comparison is always `false`.

---

```
parent.find('.totalAll');
```

This line alone doesn't do anything usefull.